# react-scroll having problems with ES6

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using [react-scroll](https://github.com/fisshy/react-scroll) but in the documentation it is using ES5

So far my code is as follows

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Scroll from 'react-scroll';

class Footer extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  scrollToTop() {
    scroll.scrollToTop();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <footer id='footer' className="container-fluid">
        <a className="black-link" id="toTop" onClick={this.scrollToTop}>
          <div className="dotted-line"></div>
          <i className="fa fa-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></i>
          Back to Top
        </a>
      </footer>
    );
  }
}

export default Footer;
```

However I'm getting `TypeError: scroll.scrollToTop is not a function`

In the documentation I see the following `var`s but im not sure exactly what to do with them as im pretty new with ES6

```
var Link       = Scroll.Link;
var Element    = Scroll.Element;
var Events     = Scroll.Events;
var scroll     = Scroll.animateScroll;
var scrollSpy  = Scroll.scrollSpy;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this to import the `scroll` function (replace your second line with this):

```
import {animateScroll as scroll} from 'react-scroll';
```

The `react-scroll` module exports an object with all the methods.

When you import default you get this object. You can either use the methods individually using the `.` operator (for example: `Scroll.animateScroll()`), or you can use something like destructing in ES6 to "extract" individual method out of the object into the current scope (like I've done above).

More on how import works in JS: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Comment: Perfect! can you explain a little bit why this works?